# Get rows from pandas dataframe based on a condition of a column after groupby and TimeGrouper

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with timestamps and would like to get the number of 'y' per day in general, as well as the number of 'y' per day by group. So as an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
               'action': ['n','n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'y'],
               'timestamp': pd.to_datetime(
                           ['2016-03-01 10:38:42','2016-03-01 10:38:42', '2016-03-01 10:38:42',
                            '2016-03-01 10:38:42', '2016-03-01 10:38:42',
                            '2016-03-02 10:38:42', '2016-03-02 10:38:42',
                            '2016-03-03 10:38:42', '2016-03-03 10:38:42',
                            '2016-03-03 10:38:42', '2016-03-03 10:38:42']),
               'group': ['A','A','A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','A', 'A']
                   })

df.set_index(keys='timestamp', inplace = True)
df
```

Here is what the dataframe looks like:
[image]
So far my approach has been:

```
grouper = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('D')])
```

And here I'm not sure what to do. What I want is the number of 'y' per day:

```
timestamp  |  count
2016-03-01 |    1
2016-03-02 |    1
2016-03-03 |    2
```

Also I would like to get the number of 'y' per day for each group. 
In this case we should have 4 for A and 0 for B. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first group by both days and column `group`.  I subsequently join with a secondary grouping just on days.

```
per_day_group = df.assign(
    yes=df.action.eq('y').astype(np.uint8)
).groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('D'), 'group']).yes.sum()

print(per_day_group)

timestamp   group
2016-03-01  A        1
            B        0
2016-03-02  A        1
2016-03-03  A        2
            B        0
Name: yes, dtype: uint8
```

---

```
per_day_group.to_frame('per_day_grp').join(
    per_day_group.groupby(level=0).sum().rename('per_day'))

                  per_day_grp  per_day
timestamp  group                      
2016-03-01 A                1        1
           B                0        1
2016-03-02 A                1        1
2016-03-03 A                2        2
           B                0        2
```

Answer (score 1):

`groupby` returns an iterable of `pd.DataFrame` subframes, where each subframe corresponding with each "group slice" of data. In your case a built-in won't do, but you can get what you want using [`pd.GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
>>> df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D')).apply(lambda d: len(d[d['action'] == 'y']))
<<< timestamp
2016-03-01    1
2016-03-02    1
2016-03-03    2
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

For the purpose of illustration, here's a more indirect way of doing it:

```
df['action'].map(lambda d: d == 'y').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='D')).sum()
```

This converts your `y` and `n` to `1` and `0`, respectively, and then just sums them. In general, a very useful trick to know.

Getting `y` totals for `A` and `B` isn't much different:

```
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda d: len(d[d['action'] == 'y']))
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution I can think of is

```
(df.action == 'y').resample('D').sum()
```

```
timestamp
2016-03-01    1.0
2016-03-02    1.0
2016-03-03    2.0
Freq: D, Name: action, dtype: float64
```

To elaborate,

1. `df.action == 'y'` is a boolean series with a datetime index.
2. `resample('D')` gives a `DatetimeIndexResampler`, similar in functionality to a `DataFrameGroupBy` object.
3. `sum()` implicitly coerces the boolean series within each group to an integer data type and computes the sum, effectively counting only those values where `df.action == 'y'`.

Following similar logic, you can use

```
(df.action == 'y').groupby(df.group).sum()
```

```
group
A    4.0
B    0.0
Name: action, dtype: float64
```

to get the `'y'`-count per group.